# How to sort data on the bases of Priority HIGH,Medium and Low in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

```
sealed class Priority{
    object High : Priority()
    object Medium : Priority()
    object Low : Priority()
}
```

I did not be able to sort the data in lazy column on the basis of high,medium and low

Answer (score 0):

Change your sealed class to this

```
sealed class Priority(value: Int){
    object High : Priority(3)
    object Medium : Priority(2)
    object Low : Priority(1)
}
```

And sort your items by `priority.value`